# How does JS know what to do on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I write the following ReactJS code in render

```
return (
   <div>
    {this.props.something.questions.map((q, index) => (<span key={index} onClick={() => { this.somefunction(index) }}>{index + 1}</span>))}
   </div>
)
```

Once bundling and all is done, I get the following on inspect element of rendered HTML.

```
<div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
</div>
```

My Question is, all these buttons (spans) are clickable, they do something once clicked. And they are working just fine, only trouble is, I am not able to understand how is it actually working.

All the spans have no id, not unique class, then when I click on any of these, how does the JS in background, gets to know which button/span is pressed.

PS. Code works perfectly fine, I just want to know the working.
Also, I found an existing question, but since it was not answered, re-questioning.

Comment: The array index is passed to `this.somefunction(index)` within the `onClick` callback. That specific value would then be used within `someFunction`

Comment: @charlietfl, but that is JSX and not what will be actually rendered, and in second piece of code, u can see what is getting rendered, a list of SPANs without any onClick in them. So how is browser/JS able to understand what to do on click, is my question. Anways, i have been able to get some clarity from the other answers that have been posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a react expert, but in general, there are ways to attach event listeners to elements without using classes or IDs.

Since react is 'just javascript' it's likely that the html elements are created in javascript in a closure, so that event listeners can be attached without creating global variables, or creating classes/IDs for every element with a click handler.

If you want more information about how those spans work in your browser, go to the elements tab in devtools, and click on the 'Event Listeners' section.

Comment: I think i understand, so basically, when Reactjs is creating the HTML (DOM, whatever, i am noob), at that time, it associate an event listener for those DOM Elements. in the following manner
element.addEventListener(event, listener);
But, now the thing is, i noticed that all the buttons have the same EventListner associated. then how is the eventListner function of ReactJS able to figure which element invoked it? Well, surely the eventListner function of reactjs will receive the element which invoked it, but all those elements are same, or are they not?

Comment: When an event handler is called, an `event` object is passed into the handler, which includes more specific information about the event, such as the specific HTML element that was the source of the event. All of those spans are different elements, even if they have no distinguishing features.

Answer (score 0):

You will find there is only one single event listener registered on the native DOM for the click event. You can confirm this with `getEventListeners()`, which will output `{click: Array(1)}`. Each and every event can have multiple handlers, even though each of them is actually being listened to only once by the real DOM. Event handlers have corresponding fiber nodes in the virtual DOM and React handles dispatching these events internally. If you want to take a deep dive, [look here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react-dom/src/events/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js#L32)

Comment: Hi, thank u for ur answer.,

getEventListeners()
undefined  <<RETURNS UNDEFINED